# Need support about fglrx package on vivid

Tags: fglrx

I Need support about installing fglrx driver on ubuntu-gnome vivid 15.04 , i installed the fglrx fglrx-core fglrx-dev the important libs,The packages are installed correctly,but im not sure the fglrx built the modules correctly to the kernel ,I configured xorg.conf then rebooted but the splash screen hangup I cant enter my lvm password because the splash is hangup ,i have chance to boot in rescure mod i founded the fglrx working on the system i tryed to change xorg.conf to solve the splash screen hangup but there is not work i edited my grub configuration but this not work too i try to found soulation , but i think there is a bug in vivd 3.19.0-15 kernel any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `nomodeset` boot parameter. For quick test, press `e` key in grub, find the line starting with `linux /vmlinuz...`, add `nomodeset` in the end and press `Ctrl+X`.

Regrading `xorg.conf`, this file is not required except if you need some specific configuration. You can try to backup and remove it.

If `nomodeset` parameter helps to boot without an issue, you can try delete package `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` (open-source driver) which may conflict with `fglrx` (proprietary driver)